# Shortcut key to show unsaved changes in Sublime Text 3

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sublimetext3

How can I set the shortcut key for right key -> show unsaved changes in Sublime Text 3?

I have tried

```
{ "keys": ["alt+f10"], "command": "show_unsaved_change" },
```

but it does not work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have the wrong command name, the correct command name is `diff_changes`:

```
{ "keys": ["ctrl+alt+d"], "command": "diff_changes" }
```

Comment: how can i find this result from official docs in [sublime text](https://www.sublimetext.com)?

Comment: It is not part of the Default Key Bindings (menu: `Preferences` -> `Key Bindings`) that ships with Sublime Text 3.

Comment: Here is documentation reference, so you can add a shortcut for "Show Unsaved Changes", using any key combination you want: https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/3/key_bindings.html (search the page for "diff_changes"). This link shows how to add this command to the `Command Palette`: https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/add-show-unsaved-changes-to-command-palette/36803/2